# Not using Auto Layout, yet see 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' error

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, autolayout

I'm not using Auto Layout in any of my nib files. I'm loading a NSViewController and then adding its view to another NSView manually. However when I do that, I am seeing this error:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

This makes no sense to me since I don't have autolayout enabled anywhere. I have specifically disabled it. I have control over the NSViewController being loaded and the NSView I'm adding it's view to. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto layout is enabled (or not) at the window level. If *any* view in the window has had constraints added to it or overrides `+requiresConstraintBasedLayout` to return `YES`, then auto layout is enabled for the window. Any views which are not coded to participate in auto layout would probably have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` left on, so they would still work just as they would in a springs-and-struts window.

It's possible that, under certain circumstances, Cocoa might add constraints. Certain Cocoa views, such as `NSStackView`, return `YES` from `+requiresConstraintBasedLayout`.

Are you using some of the most recent features in your window, such as title bar accessories?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am using 'NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController', if that's what you mean, in order to fake an increased height of the Window. I'm not using a NSStackView and simply have nibs with NSOutlineView loaded into the main window. Do you think the accessory view controller is the culprit? I've checked all my nibs and they have 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' set to 'NO' - should they all be set to YES instead?

Comment: In general, top-level views in a NIB should have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` (TAMIC) set to `YES`. Some controller will load the NIB and add the view into a view hierarchy. If that controller is auto-layout-aware, it will adjust TAMIC if desired. If that controller is not aware of auto layout, then you want TAMIC set to `YES` in case the window is using auto layout, so it behaves as expected. For views within windows or top-level views, TAMIC should be `NO` if the NIB has auto layout enabled, `YES` otherwise.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for that, I'll go around turning them back on and see if this fixes it for me.

Comment: Yes, I do suspect that `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` enables auto layout for the window. For example, consider its `layoutAttribute` property, which use auto layout terminology and values to control where the accessory view goes.